# Segmentation fault when trying to sort string elements

Tags: string, sorting, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to make a program that takes a string as an input (made up of 0,1, and 2), and checks if the string[i+1] element is greater than string[i]. if it is greater, the program returns 1, if it is not greater, it returns -1. I keep getting a segmentation fault and i have no idea where it could be.

There is more code to the rest of the program but i have confirmed that the rest works and only raises a Seg Fault when "sort" is called.

My code:

```
sort:  
enter 0,0
pusha

mov edx, dword [ebp+8]        ;address of string
mov edi, dword [ebp+12]       ;first index
mov esi, dword [ebp+16]       ;second index
LOOPYDOOPY:
  cmp byte [edx+edi], 0       ;check if the character at first index is 0
  je RETMINUS                                                   
  cmp byte [edx+esi], 0       ;if character at second is 0
  je RETPLUS
  mov al, byte [edx+esi]      ;if first element is greater than second element
  cmp byte [edx+edi], al
  jl RETMINUS
  cmp byte [edx+edi], al      ;firstt < second
  jg RETPLUS
  inc edi
  inc esi
  jmp LOOPYDOOPY
RETPLUS:
  popa
  mov eax, 1                  ;return 1
  jmp END
RETMINUS:
  popa
  mov eax, -1                 ;return -1
END:
  leave
  ret
```

Comment: If you are different user than poster of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41204831/4271923), then check this one too, also my answer, it may help you with your code, as the task looks to be the same one and your code quality looks to be similar as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, you were confirmed that the sort raises segfault, not that the rest of code works, quite opposite.

Actually the sort itself is OK, I copied it 1:1 from your question and added only the test calling the sort and displaying results (you can verify I didn't modify single character in your "sort:"), and it works:

(To verify go to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php and paste this source + run it).

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    lea ebx,[testString]
    xor ecx,ecx     ; ecx (i) = 0
.loopI:
    cmp [ebx+ecx+2],byte 0
    je  .allCompared  ; not "all", should have been ecx+1 above.
    lea edx,[ecx+1] ; edx (j) = i+1
.loopJ:
    ; call sort
    push edx        ; j
    push ecx        ; i
    push ebx        ; string adr (! OP missing the diff betwen adr and content)
    call sort
    add esp,12
    ; display result
    mov esi,ecx     ; copy i/j to esi/edi
    mov edi,edx
    test eax,eax
    js  .firstWasSmaller
    xchg esi,edi    ; swap esi/edi, esi is "smaller" now
.firstWasSmaller:
    pushad
    call displaySingleString
    mov  edx,lenLess
    mov  ecx,msgLess
    call displayStr
    xchg esi,edi    ; swap esi/edi, esi is "smaller" now
    call displaySingleString
    mov  edx,lenNL
    mov  ecx,msgNL
    call displayStr
    popad
    ; continue in loop
    inc edx
    cmp [ebx+edx],byte 0
    jnz .loopJ
    inc ecx
    jmp .loopI

.allCompared:
    mov eax, 1      ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

displaySingleString: ; display partial string from testString+esi
    mov edx,testLen
    sub edx,esi
    lea ecx,[testString+esi]
displayStr:
    mov ebx, 1      ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax, 4      ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel
    ret

; original poster code follows, as is (intact):

sort:  
enter 0,0
pusha

mov edx, dword [ebp+8]        ;address of string
mov edi, dword [ebp+12]       ;first index
mov esi, dword [ebp+16]       ;second index
LOOPYDOOPY:
  cmp byte [edx+edi], 0       ;check if the character at first index is 0
  je RETMINUS                                                   
  cmp byte [edx+esi], 0       ;if character at second is 0
  je RETPLUS
  mov al, byte [edx+esi]      ;if first element is greater than second element
  cmp byte [edx+edi], al
  jl RETMINUS
  cmp byte [edx+edi], al      ;firstt < second
  jg RETPLUS
  inc edi
  inc esi
  jmp LOOPYDOOPY
RETPLUS:
  popa
  mov eax, 1                  ;return 1
  jmp END
RETMINUS:
  popa
  mov eax, -1                 ;return -1
END:
  leave
  ret

; read only test data + formatting strings

section .rodata

testString: db '00100102', 0
testLen equ $ - testString - 1

msgLess db  ' < '
lenLess equ $ - msgLess

msgNL   db  0x0a
lenNL   equ $ - msgNL
```

Output I get:

```
sh-4.3$ nasm -f elf *.asm; ld -m elf_i386 -s -o demo *.o
sh-4.3$ demo
00100102 < 0100102
00100102 < 100102
00100102 < 00102
00100102 < 0102
00100102 < 102
00100102 < 02
00100102 < 2
0100102 < 100102
00102 < 0100102
0100102 < 0102
0100102 < 102
0100102 < 02
0100102 < 2
00102 < 100102
0102 < 100102
100102 < 102
02 < 100102
100102 < 2
00102 < 0102
00102 < 102
00102 < 02
00102 < 2
0102 < 102
0102 < 02
0102 < 2
02 < 102
102 < 2
sh-4.3$
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying in the first line of your answer. Are you saying that his original code works fine, *with no segfault*? Otherwise, what have you changed in his code?

Comment: @CodyGray exactly, the code in question works OK. I didn't change anything in it. I just call it properly, so it doesn't segfault. I sort of guess the OP has in original code something like `buffer: resb 32` and put's that as argument before call with `push dword [buffer]` instead of `push buffer`. Then the sort routine segfaults on invalid memory access, as the `[ebp+8]` is not `buffer` but something like `0x30313030` (`'0010'`).  (I somehow hope my answer will give OP new ideas how to write certain things in x86 assembly).